# Get all hosts on LAN network in C?

Tags: c, windows, network-programming, lan

Is it possible to get all the hosts on a LAN network(using C). I need to get the IP addresses and host names.

Comment: I don't know of a truly portable way to do this -- which is not to say there isn't one.  If you have an internal DNS server, you might be able to query that and filter based on your local IP configuration (i.e. anything that matches 10.*.*.*).  But even that won't catch machines that aren't registered in DNS -- which some might not be e.g. for security reasons.

Comment: It is possible, apparenly. Win32 has IpHelper API which gives information about available networks, so you can choose ones that look sufficiently local, and then use DnsQuery to get host names. Usage of ICMP to ping is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10475937/448220), the to ping all hosts in your subnet and see which respond or access the ARP cache. The first approach is accomplished by creating a raw socket using

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP));
```

However, raw sockets basically give you only the IP header so you need to construct the ICMP echo packet yourself. After you constructed it, then you just send them to every IP in the subnet using `sendto()` and wait for response. For the second approach I suggest reading something like [this](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock.html).

As for determining the host names, it depends on whether the hosts have DNS or NETBIOS names. If you have a DNS configured on your LAN, you may get away with calling `getaddrinfo()` on the the addresses that respond. Unfortunately, I do not have any idea how to find out the NETBIOS name of any given IP.